# Redirect to rename remote images so as to get around adblock

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, reverse-proxy, adblock

I'm working with a partner who provides me with images of their products from an API. The images are sent as URLs and they expect me to just use these URLs in img tags, not download the images and serve them locally.

The problem is that 1/4 of users use ad blockers and their images have URLs like `https://example.com/ad-image/ads/1234/500.jpg` which read to ad blockers as ads (which they are of course, technically). Would it be possible to set up a redirect so  an img tag like `<img src="/image-redirects/500.jpg">` would show them the image from `https://example.com/ad-image/ads/1234/500.jpg`? Is that feasible? Would they not show up anyways because they're remotely hosted images?

Comment: _“Would they not show up anyways because they're remotely hosted images?”_ - what do you mean by that? Most ads are “remotely hosted”, I would guess.

Comment: A redirection won't trick an adblocker. If you really insist in trying to be smart and break the clear will of the user (so if you are willing to frustrate and annoy the user) you will need to proxy the requests. Which will add load to your setup. My advice: never try to be smarter than your users. If the do not want to see those images, do not force them to.

Comment: @arkascha you're probably right and generally I agree with the sentiment, but these aren't actually ads, they're images of products on a page full of information about the products. The filenames have the word "ads" in the paths so adblockers keep them from showing up.

Comment: Sounds fishy, sorry. Ad blockers do not react to parts of the "path", they control from what sources additional resources are loaded and what the connection between the actual page and those sources is. Above I told you the only way to get around this which you appartly did not read.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I just set up a cron job to d/l the images daily and host them locally.

Comment: But adblockers do look at filenames & paths. It was only the images that had the word "ad" in the path and filename that were getting blocked by ABP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would it be possible to set up a redirect so an img tag like `<img src="/image-redirects/500.jpg">` would show them the image from `https://example.com/ad-image/ads/1234/500.jpg`?

Yes, you can, but not with an external "redirect" as that will simply present the target URL to the browser on the redirect response (and be blocked - if the browser is blocking simply based on keywords in the URl).

#### Reverse Proxy

You will either need to configure your server as a reverse proxy (using mod_proxy and related modules with ideally `ProxyPass` / `ProxyPassReverse` in the server config), then you can do something like the following in `.htaccess` (before the WordPress front-controller) using mod_rewrite to route the request through mod_proxy:

```
RewriteRule ^image-redirects/(\d+\.jpg)$ https://example.com/ad-image/ads/1234/$1 [P]
```

(Assuming `500` is a dynamic filename consisting of digits only - as in your example).

#### PHP Script to fetch image

Or, you internally rewrite such requests to a PHP script that fetches the image from the remote server and sends this back in the response.

For example, in `.htaccess`, using mod_rewrite (again, before the WP front-controller):

```
RewriteRule ^image-redirects/(\d+\.jpg)$ image-fetch-script.php?file=$1 [L]
```

In `image-fetch-script.php` you can examine the `file` URL parameter and fetch the intended image from the remote server and send this back to the client in the response. You could also cache the image on your server for a period of time. However, the fact that they want you to fetch the images directly from their server may be because they are logging *impressions*, so local caching would affect this.

Example `image-fetch-script.php` could be something like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Fetch remote image and send to client
 */

// Remote URL from which to fetch images
$remoteBaseUrl = 'https://example.com/ad-image/ads/1234/';

// Permitted file extensions / mime-types
// NB: If using CURL, can get the mime-type from the HTTP response instead
$mimeTypes = [
    'gif' => 'image/gif',
    'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
    'png' => 'image/png',
    'webp' => 'image/webp',
];

// Get the reqd file the "file" URL parameter in the rewritten URL
$file = $_GET['file'] ?? null;
$remoteUrl = null;

// Validate filename format
// Or even check against a known list of files?
$filenameRegex = '/^[\w-]+\.('.implode('|',array_keys($mimeTypes)).')$/';
if (preg_match($filenameRegex, $file, $matches)) {
    header('Content-Type: '.$mimeTypes[$matches[1]]);
    $remoteUrl = $remoteBaseUrl.$file;

    // OPTIONAL: Check cache here...
    // readfile() and exit if current.

    // Using readfile()
    // - simple, but does not provide any error handling on the HTTP response
    //   eg. if the remote file does not exist etc.
    //$bytes = readfile($remoteUrl);
    //if ($bytes === false) {
    //    General 500 Internal Server Error
    //    http_response_code(500);  
    //} else {
    //    // No error - assume success!
    //    // But there could have been an HTTP response "error" that is lost
    //}
    //exit;

    // Using CURL
    $ch = curl_init($remoteUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    $curlError = curl_errno($ch);
    if ($curlError) $curlError .= ': '.curl_error($ch);
    $httpStatus = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($curlError) {
        // Only set header when debugging, otherwise could expose the target URL
        //header('X-CURL-ERROR: '.$curlError);

        // General 500 Internal Server Error
        http_response_code(500);    
    }
    // CURL request is OK, but could still be an HTTP failure...
    else {
        // OK - serve image
        if ($httpStatus === 200) {
            // OPTIONAL: Save to cache...
            echo $content;
        }
        // Pass through HTTP status from CURL request... 404, 403, etc...
        else {
             http_response_code($httpStatus);
        }
    }
    exit;
}

// Default failure... "Bad Request"
http_response_code(400);
```

Comment: Ah this seems like a good way to do it! I'll try this.

Comment: I've update my answer to include an example PHP script to fetch the remote image.